# LispBox how to break a loop?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am using LispBox on MacOSX.
My question is, how can I break a loop in this environment?

for example. I typed:

> CL-USER> (loop)

then, it is in a loop, I don't know how to break it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `C-c C-c` (`slime-interrupt`).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Mac version of ctrl-c (I believe it's command-c)? Sending an interrupt signal works for many lisp systems. SBCL will, for example, let you choose among several restarts. I don't know how Clozure (the compiler that comes with lispbox) will handle it.